# Signature Generation and Verification for GET/POST requests in Android and ASP.net Core Application (C#) respectively

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, query-string

**UPDATE (2018-04-27)**

It looks I localized problem a bit. Verification works on .net side if the query parameter contains only 1 parameter. For example, ?param1=1 works fine. However, ?param1=1&param2=2 does NOT get verified. I think that the problem is on the string encoding of the ampersand sign that is seperating the parameters. In the follwing additional code section I provide how I generate the query string from a hashmap. So briefly, the problem still persists with query string with multiple parameters.

```js
public static String getQueryString( HashMap<String, Object> params) throws SignatureGenerationException {
        
if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
     
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     
     sb.append("?");

     int count = 0;
     for (HashMap.Entry<String, Object> e : params.entrySet()) {
           
           count++;
           
           sb.append(e.getKey()).
             append("=").
             append(e.getValue().toString());

           if(count != params.keySet().size()) {
              sb.append("&");
           }
     }

      return sb.toString();            
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have an **ASP.net Core Web API** application that accepts GET/POST requests from an **android client written in Java**. Before sending the GET/POST requests, the android client generates a key pair (i.e. public/private key pair) and stores it in the android key-store (See **code section 1**). Later, I use this generated private key to create a signature for my GET and POST requests within the android client and send the requests to the ASP.net Web API application. For the GET requests, I sign the access token and query parameter string (See **code section 2**) while I sign the accesstoken and request body for the POST requests. In **code section 3**, you can see how I verify the signature for the get/post requests in the ASP.net core application. I am basically verifiying by using the public key  that is retrieved from the keypair that was generated in android client. I saved this public key in the database manually and this public key is available to the C# code in the ASP.net core web API application.

**QUESTION**
In the code section 3 below, there are lines that are highlighted in between STAR signs. Both of these lines return false. However, I think that I am doing signature generation in Java side (code section 2) and signature verification (code section 3) currectly. What do you think I am doing wrong here? Is there something I am doing inappropriately either in Java code or in C# code. Am I missing st fundamentally? My public key is provided  in very below in this question text. I am basically signing the request with private key on Android side and then verify it with public key on C# side (i.e. ASP.net Core web API side).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**CODE SECTION 1**

```js
 private void buildKeyStore() throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException {
        if (mKeyPair == null) {

            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");

            Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
            notAfter.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

            kpg.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    AccessConfigurationBean.DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT|KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + AccessConfigurationBean.DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_ALIAS))
                    .setKeySize(2048)
                    .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)                        .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)                        
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                    .setKeyValidityStart(notBefore.getTime())
                    .setKeyValidityEnd(notAfter.getTime())
                    .build());


            mKeyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
            mPrivateKey = mKeyPair.getPrivate();
            mPublicKey = mKeyPair.getPublic();

            System.out.println("--- BEGIN KEY STORE PUBLIC KEY ---");
            System.out.println(getPublicKeyAsString(mPublicKey));
            System.out.println("--- END KEY STORE PUBLIC KEY ---");
        }
    }

  private static String getPublicKeyAsString(PublicKey pKey) {
    byte[] publicKey = pKey.getEncoded();
    String encodedPublicKey = Base64.encodeToString(publicKey, 
    Base64.NO_WRAP);        
    return encodedPublicKey;
}
```

**CODE SECTION 2**

```js
public static String generateSignatureForGetService(String accessToken,
                                                        String queryString) throws SignatureGenerationException {
        String input = accessToken.trim() + queryString;
        String base64Signature = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("INPUT to SIGN: " + input);
            base64Signature = signSHA256RSA(input);
            System.out.println("SIGNATURE: " + base64Signature);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            SignatureGenerationException signatureEx = new SignatureGenerationException(msg, e);
            throw signatureEx;
        }
        return base64Signature;
    }
    
    
    // Create base64 encoded signature using SHA256/RSA.
    private static String signSHA256RSA(String input) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(Constants.KEY_STORE_ALIAS, null);
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        s.initSign(((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getPrivateKey());
        s.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] signature = s.sign();
        return Base64.encodeToString(signature, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

**CODE SECTION 3**

```js
try
{
    var clientPublicKey = await certificateGetter.GetClientCertificatePublicKeyAsync(clientId);

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var signature = context.GetSignature();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = ForbiddenCode;
            context.AddHeader(ExpectHeader, EmptySignature);
            await context.WriteErrorAsync(EmptySignature);
            return;
        }
     
        byte[] dataHashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);

        #region GetBody
        var initialBody = context.Request.Body;
        context.Request.EnableRewind();
        var bufferBody = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.ContentLength)];
        await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(bufferBody, 0, bufferBody.Length);
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        #endregion

        byte[] plainTextBytes;

        byte[] plainTextBytesToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(context.GetAccessToken());
        byte[] plainTextBytesQueryParameters = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(context.Request.QueryString.Value);

        if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
        {
            plainTextBytes = new byte[plainTextBytesToken.Length + bufferBody.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(plainTextBytesToken, 0, plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytesToken.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bufferBody, 0, plainTextBytes, plainTextBytesToken.Length, bufferBody.Length);
        }
        else if (context.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Get)
        {
            plainTextBytes = new byte[plainTextBytesToken.Length + plainTextBytesQueryParameters.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(plainTextBytesToken, 0, plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytesToken.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(plainTextBytesQueryParameters, 0, plainTextBytes, plainTextBytesToken.Length, plainTextBytesQueryParameters.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = ForbiddenCode;
            context.AddHeader(ExpectHeader, InvalidSignature);
            await context.WriteErrorAsync(InvalidSignature);
            return;
        }

        rsaProvider.FromXmlString(clientPublicKey);

 //***************************************************
 // HERE IT IS BEGIN
 //BOTH of the method invocations in below two lines return false. 
    //I expect them to return true instead since I am doing signature 
    //generation on Android side in code section 1 & 2 by using proper 
    //standard Android Java API (Perhaps I am doing a wrong assumption here 
    //though).
 //What do you think I am doing wrong here? What would ve the fix? Is 
    //there any wrong API usage either in C# side or in Android/Java side?
         bool isVerified = rsaProvider.VerifyData(plainTextBytes, HashAlgorithm.Create(SHA256), dataHashBytes);
         bool isVerified2 = rsaProvider.VerifyData(plainTextBytes, dataHashBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
   // HERE IT IS END
 //***********************************************
        if (!isVerified)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = ForbiddenCode;
            context.AddHeader(ExpectHeader, InvalidSignature);
            await context.WriteErrorAsync(InvalidSignature);
            return;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MyLogManager.Log(ex);
    context.Response.StatusCode = BadRequest;
    context.AddHeader(ExpectHeader, InvalidSignature);
    await context.WriteErrorAsync(InvalidSignature);
    return;
}
```

**PUBLIC KEY:**

```js
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- 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 -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

NOTE: Abpve public key is retrieved from the getPublicKeyAsString method shown in code section 2.